# Players who have won Champions League / Copa Libertadores and World Cup in the same year

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup, champions-league, copa-libertadores

[This ESPN Stats & Info twitter feed](https://twitter.com/ESPNStatsInfo/status/1017168581899976709) states:

> 10 players in World Cup history have won the Champions League and World Cup in the same year.
>
> With Real Madrid's Raphael Varanae of France, and Luka Modric & Mateo Kovavic of Croatia in the final, there is guaranteed to be an 11th.

[image: cl & wc]

So, *who are the 10 players who have achieved this feat previously?*

Also, *how many and who are the players that have won [Copa Libertadores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copa_Libertadores) and a World Cup in same year?*

Answer (score 3):

There are 11 players who have won the Champions League (including the European Cup) and the World Cup in the same year:

**1974: [West Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#_West_Germany) and [Bayern Munich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973%E2%80%9374_European_Cup):**

- [Uli Hoeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uli_Hoene%C3%9F), [Gerd Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller), [Franz Beckenbauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Beckenbauer), [Paul Breitner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Breitner), [Hans-Georg Schwarzenbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-Georg_Schwarzenbeck), [Sepp Maier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepp_Maier), [Jupp Kapellmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupp_Kapellmann)

**1998: [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#France) and [Real Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997%E2%80%9398_UEFA_Champions_League):**

- [Christian Karembeu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Karembeu)

**2002: [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Brazil) and [Real Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001%E2%80%9302_UEFA_Champions_League):**

- [Roberto Carlos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Carlos)

**2014: [Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Germany) and [Real Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013%E2%80%9314_UEFA_Champions_League):**

- [Sami Khedira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sami_Khedira)

**2018: [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#France) and [Real Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017%E2%80%9318_UEFA_Champions_League):**

- [Raphaël Varane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapha%C3%ABl_Varane)

---

There are 10 players who have won the Copa Libertadores and the World Cup in the same year:

**1962: [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#_Brazil) and [Santos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_Copa_Libertadores):**

- [Gilmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gylmar_dos_Santos_Neves), [Mauro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauro_Ramos), [Zito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Ely_de_Miranda), [Coutinho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B4nio_Wilson_Vieira_Hon%C3%B3rio), [Pelé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pel%C3%A9), [Pepe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Macia), [Mengálvio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meng%C3%A1lvio_Pedro_Figueir%C3%B3)

**1986: [Argentina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#_Argentina) and [River Plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_Copa_Libertadores):**

- [Héctor Enrique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9ctor_Enrique), [Nery Pumpido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nery_Pumpido), [Oscar Ruggeri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Ruggeri)

---

References:

[The 10 Players To Have Won The European Cup And World Cup In Same Year](http://www.sportbible.com/football/news-take-a-bow-the-10-players-to-have-won-the-european-and-world-cup-in-same-year-20180709)

Comment: Interestingly, despite Boca Juniors winning both 1977 and 1978 Copa Libertadores titles, they didn't provide a single player for the Argentine squad winning the 1978 World Cup played at home.